# Linked answers should (within linked list) resolve to linked answer

Tags: feature-request, bug, information-display, linked-questions

**EDIT: unsure if it's a bug or not - applying tag until certain**

Currently, all links under the "Linked" list take you to the question. In the message body, however, these links will take you to the actual answer or question that was linked to.

Would be great if the "Linked" list displayed the relevant score for question/answer linked to, and took you to what was actually linked. UI wise, it could be the same as search:

**Link to the question "How do I do the impossible with CSS":**

`2` How do I do the impossible with CSS?

**Link to an answer within "How do I do the impossible with CSS":**

`24` A: How do I do the impossible with CSS?