# What to do about a closed-as-duplicate question whose answers are arguably superior to answers to referenced question?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions

I just noticed the update to [Is there any official Stack Overflow Android app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182709/is-there-any-official-stack-overflow-android-app/182713#182713), which now includes critical information not available in the answers contained in the question that this has been closed as a duplicate of.

The specifics of these specific questions/answers aside, what's the recommend response to encountering a situation like this?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209627/147247 is not a dupe, because it wanted to change the system, but my answer is what I think you should do in this case (request a merge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering the general question, not this case in particular.

If the answers on a dupe are better than the ones on the original, one option is to nominate it for *merging*.  This combines the questions into one (the person doing the merge dccides which question to keep) with all of the answers.

I *believe* this leaves the dupe question intact, with an annotation saying "merged into (link)".  It's possible that I'm mis-remembering and the merge deletes the dupe.  If so, and if the dupe is valuable as a signpost, then it's easy enough to undelete it afterward.

There is no way<sup>1</sup> to move only *some* answers from one question to another; it's all-or-nothing.

<sup>1</sup> Well, presumably devs could hack the database directly, but don't ask for that.  It's probably dangerous and almost certainly not worth the effort.